# Database indexing on non-key field

Tags: database, sorting, indexing, data-structures, database-schema

I have a question regarding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1130/1925388).
I also posted this question as a comment to that answer, but didn't get any response.

It states that in the case of indexing on a non-key field, the schema would be:

```
Field name       Data type      Size on disk
firstName        Char(50)       50 bytes
(record pointer) Special        4 bytes
```

My question is that why is there a need to store `firstName` again? Isn't the pointer enough? We'll just have to simply change the sorting comparison function to compare on `(*pointer).firstName`, rather than `firstName`.

Comment: In theory, it is not needed: the char(50) field could be pulled from the basetable. In practice, this would cause **both** the basetable and the index to be pulled fron disk, costing more IO bandwith and bufferspace.

Comment: @wildplasser Makes sense!

Comment: @wildplasser Since I'm not getting any answers, would you like to convert your comment to an answer so that I can close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the answer given as a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35749439/database-indexing-on-non-key-field#comment59175074_35749439) by @wildplasser :

> In theory, it is not needed: the char(50) field could be pulled from
>   the basetable. In practice, this would cause both the basetable and
>   the index to be pulled fron disk, costing more IO bandwith and
>   bufferspace.